# If statement not working (px left) jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'm working on a fairly simple jQuery slider. But I'm hitting a block (well a few). I try to keep this as simple as I can. I have a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dXYCP/

In the jsFiddle I have an if statement, that when the de div #slider_ul has 0 or less px on the left condition it should hide the arrow button. But it does not work.

Comment: Where is the call to slider function?

Comment: It doesn't work because your if statement with `'#slider_ul'.left` should be `$('#slider_ul').left()`

Comment: Nothing understand from jsfiddle, really.

Comment: @Vega I guess this is a handler of `animate`. However, even with the correct syntax and code, the button is not hiding. There is some logical error in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) (or [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), depends on markup):

```
if ($('#slider_ul').position().left > 0) { ... }
```

Comment: @SnakeEyes Yes, I also thought about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a slider as in this demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dXYCP/7/

**JS:**

```
 $(function() {

    slider();

    $('.arrow_left').click(function() {
       $('#slider_ul').animate({
            'left': '+=470px'
        }, slider);
    });

    $('.arrow_right').click(function() {        
        $('#slider_ul').animate({
            'left': '-=470px'
        }, slider);
    });

    function slider (){        
        var sliderPos = parseInt($('#slider_ul').css('left'), 10);
        if (sliderPos < 0) {
            $('.arrow_left').css('visibility', 'visible');
        } else {
            $('.arrow_left').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }

        if (sliderPos < (-470*2)) {
            $('.arrow_right').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        } else {
            $('.arrow_right').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    };

});
```

**CSS:**

```
.arrow_left{
    margin-top:40px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.arrow_right{
    margin-top:40px;
    float:right;
    margin-left:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#slider{
    padding-top:15px;
    float:left;
    width: 470px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vega, it seems I was a bity hasty with my original code. Changed your code a bit to animate the buttons. I like the "math" solution with the right arrow!